# Collapsing bottom panel for search results

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I would like a brief guidance on how could I achieved the following:

[image]

I have a search input on my navbar at the top of the screen. I want the user to type a keyword and when he presses [enter], a collapsing panel filled with the search results to be revealed with a transition from bottom to top covering the lower area of the map shown above.

The panel should have a toggle button attached to it, so the user can afterwards collapse it back to the bottom and reveal the whole map.

Which would be the best solution to create that kind of layout with Bootstrap 3 and pure CSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want just with css as you need a couple events on click and on enter, but the jquery to do what you want is easy enough to use / understand.

You may not want this answer but it could help other people so here we are.

First the basic layout with this html

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="side"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

and css:

```
body, html {margin:0; height:100%;}
.top {
  height:40px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.side {
  height:calc(100% - 40px);
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.container {
  height:calc(50% - 40px);
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  transition: height 0.4s linear;
}
```

It will look like in your picture where the red container is your map.

then I have added the "collapse" buttom inside the container and positioned it absolute so it will be at the bottom, right side of the container.

Time to add the event on click just to add a class to the container:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.container').toggleClass("container-full"); 
});
```

and the properties of this new class:

```
.container-full {
  height:calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

which will make the red element fill the window when click on the buttom and back if click again.

Then I have added your `input type="search"` to the `top`container and I have added this jquery:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
            $('.button').click();//Trigger search button click event
        }
    });
```

Now when you press "enter" inside the input, the function I already make to the "collapse" buttom will take place.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/ud8j5qkz/)**

```js
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.container').toggleClass("container-full"); 
});

$('input').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
            $('.button').click();//Trigger search button click event
        }
    });
```

```css
body, html {margin:0; height:100%;}
.top {
  height:40px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.side {
  height:calc(100% - 40px);
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.container {
  height:calc(50% - 40px);
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  transition: height 0.4s linear;
}
.container-full {
  height:calc(100% - 40px);
}
.button {
  height:20px;
  width:60px;
  background-color:#bbb;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
input {margin:10px 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <input type="search">
</div>
<div class="side"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```